# Error: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2' But the module is installled

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I get the error above when launching my django project, I am on windows

I have tried installing the module again and tried

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

as well.I also checked out other treads but they don't seem to work I need to fix it pretty soon so thank you in advance!

Comment: are you running on the entire machine or on a virtual environment?

Comment: 1. add your python site-packages dir
2. check the python package of psycopy2  relative version

Comment: I am running it on my IDE, and I am using python 3.10, psycopg2(2.9.5), i also dont see it in the packages list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the package directly from the Package Manager on my IDE and it works now.